# Principal value of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Trying to find the principal value of the above equation
I've done the first couple lines
\begin{align}
&e^{(1+i)(\log(-1+\sqrt{3}i)}\\
&e^{(1+i)(\ln(2)+\frac{2\pi}{3})}
\end{align}

How would I further simplify this?

Comment: You mean $\ln2+\tfrac{2\pi}{3}\color{red}{i}$.

Comment: $e^{Real}e^{i*{imaginary} }$ would get it done

Answer (score 0):

To simplify something like $e^{(a+bi)(c+di)}$, first carry out the multiplication in the exponent so you can identify the real and imaginary components of the exponent:
$$e^{(a+bi)(c+di)} = e^{(ac-bd) +i(ad + bc)}$$
Then apply the definition of exponentiating a complex number:
$$= e^{ac-bd}\cos(ad + bc) + ie^{ac-bd}\sin(ad + bc)$$
In your case, some of the exponetial factor will simplify since, for example, $e^{\ln 2} = 2$.

Personally, I like to leave things in the polar form $e^{(ac-bd)}e^{i(ad + bc)}$, but you may want to explicitly write out the real and imaginary parts of the final form as shown above. It depends on what you mean by "simplify".

**Exercise:** Write out the fully expanded form of $e^{e^{a+bi}}$.

Comment: Thanks, I've split it into the polar form you suggested as that seems the simplest way to do it, appreciate the help. I'll give that exercise a go

Answer (score 0):

$e^{(1+i)(\ln(2)+\frac{2\pi}{3}i)}$

Just continue

$e^{(\ln 2 -\frac {2\pi}3)+(\frac {2\pi}3 + \ln(2))i}=$

$\frac 2{e^{\frac {2\pi}3}} \cdot e^{(\frac {2\pi}3 + \ln(2))i}$

i.e. $re^{\theta i}$ where $r = 2e^{-\frac {2\pi}3}$ and $\theta = \frac {2\pi}3 + \ln(2)$

Comment: Of course it should.